# Trying to tonemap 14-bit grayscale video

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to generate h.264 video from raw 2-byte gray video (14-bit range encoded in 16-bit values). I can do something like:

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt gray16le -s:v 1280x720 -r 60 -i input.raw -c:v libx264 output.mp4
```

And I get video but it's pretty dark, not sure if it's clipping, doing a linear remap, or storing the 16-bit data and VLC is doing the remap. ffprobe is reporting `Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj444p(pc), 1280x720, 108 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc`

I was figuring I'd use the tonemap filter to make a better mapping. I added a filter before the output file with `-vf`.

- `tonemap=hable` errors `Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'graph 0 input from stream 0:0' and the filter 'auto_scaler_0'`
- `zscale=transfer=linear,tonemap=hable` errors `Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'Parsed_tonemap_1' and the filter 'auto_scaler_1'`
- `zscale=transfer=linear,tonemap=hable,zscale=transfer=bt709,format=yuvj444p` errors `code 3074: no path between colorspaces`

I'm not sure where to proceed from here...

Comment: Add `-bits_per_coded_sample 14` before `-i` and check. Skip the filters.

Comment: Should it be `-bits_per_raw_sample`?